# SQL convert hour to half hourly observation

Tags: sql, oracle

I've searched to forums, bout couldn't quite find an answer that helped me.
Hence, the reason fro this thread.

I have a database which contains hourly price observations.
I also have this SQL query statement, which goes in and selects/returns the hourly price observations within a certain date range.

However, I need the query to return the price observations in half-hour instead of hourly --> I guess this means, that every observations basically needs to be repeated twice, hence converting it from hourly to half-hourly.

My code is as such:

```
SELECT A.DELIVERY_START,
  A.PRICE
FROM DMA_PREP.DMA_PRICE_V a
WHERE 1                         =1
AND A.PRODUCT_BID               ='1000286'
AND a.DELIVERY_START              >= TRUNC(TRUNC(TRUNC(sysdate,'YYYY'),'YY'),'YY')
AND a.DELIVERY_PERIOD_TYPE_NAME = 'Hour'
ORDER BY A.delivery_start
```

I've tried to change 'Hour' to 'Half-hour' but without luck, as it then starts to return some completely other values from the database, which has a half-hourly tag.

So basically, I need the query to extract the data as it already does, but then convert it to half-hourly observations before printing it.

This is what the output looks like now:

01-JAN-14   35

01-JAN-14   34.97

01-JAN-14   34.03

01-JAN-14   30

01-JAN-14   28.04

01-JAN-14   29.79

01-JAN-14   29.79

01-JAN-14   29.79

01-JAN-14   29.9

01-JAN-14   30.63

01-JAN-14   33.58

01-JAN-14   34.97

01-JAN-14   44.92

01-JAN-14   35.99

01-JAN-14   35.46

01-JAN-14   37.94

01-JAN-14   59.94

01-JAN-14   71.99

01-JAN-14   57.91

01-JAN-14   47.95

01-JAN-14   44.95

01-JAN-14   40.04

01-JAN-14   34.56

01-JAN-14   34.01

02-JAN-14   36.71

Any suggestions?

Comment: please add a sample row from your database

Comment: Is there date on when a transaction has been completed? Also, provide some example data, and an example of what you'd like to have from that data?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: The use of `sysdate` and `trunc` with a date argument lead me to believe this is an Oracle question, so I tagged it appropriately.

Comment: Someone already binned it to an hourly interval. If you are lucky, it is just a view (assuming that _V signifies), so it can be modified. However, you cannot do it yourself. You need to modify the query behind that view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `union all`:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
    select t.DELIVERY_START, t.PRICE
    union all
    select t.DELIVERY_START + 1.0/(24*2), t.PRICE;
```

This uses Oracle syntax for adding half an hour because your query seems to use Oracle features.